# Inexpensive solution for catch-all emails

Tags: email, email-server

I have my own domain that I use only for redirecting e-mails to my Gmail. I'm looking for a cheap service that would allow me to do that.

Currently, I'm using GSuite, but the price of 6,5EUR seems a bit high for such a service. Are there any other reliable and cheap services that will allow me to do that?

Comment: Last time I did it, it was yet free. But it was not today, about in 2011. Unfortunately, gmail & co practically killed the cheap email providers -> what they don't do, you can't do easily. Hopefully you can find one still existing. (It was not an answer, only a comment.)

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica yes, I know it was free some time ago. Unfortunately, I didn't register it back then.

Comment: Btw, doing that professionally would require 1 linux sysadm. I estimate he would need to work with it about 4 hours per month. Counting with a $50/hour total cost of employment (very cheap, it would work only in developing countries), adding the cost of the server (can be a low-cost VPS), it would worth its price from about 50 customers like you. The service won't be very HQ (underpaid sysadms are not on the top). The chance of a small company to get 50 customers for this task is close to zero. Another problem is that this would run independently from the google -> they could consider your

Comment: server as a spammer any time. That would convert your 50 customers to 50 non-paying, angry ex-customers, and you have no way to avoid it. I think this 6.5 EUR is not a too high price.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica Sure, but I'm looking for a solution that already is on the market. I've heard that Outlook 365 has something like that, but I can't find it nor reach their support. And 6.5 EUR per month is not very cheap in my country.

Comment: There are two problems to solve: 1) the incoming mails to your domain need to be received by some server. It must be a server on the internet. Outlook and other mail clients can only get your mails from this server. 2) The mails need to be transfered into your gmail account. It can be done either by this server, or by your mail software. (Btw, I am nearly sure that outlook365 is completely incapable to read all mails incoming to a domain without some server-side support. It can read only mails to specific mail addresses.)

Comment: [If you are thinking on office365, which is effectively the paid gmail of the microsoft: their prices are astronomical, compared to this 6.5EUR]

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica I know how this works under the hood, I had my own server that was dealing with that for years, but it was a bit cheaper to move to google as I've stopped using it also for web. For now, only protonmail can handle catch-all cheaper than google, but the price difference is negligible so I'll stick with google.

Comment: Thanks the clarification! I hope you get an useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are domain registrar that provide the email catch all and forwarding service that is included in the domain registration fee or as an add on fee.

I assume you are now paying domain name registration fee (yearly) + GSuite fee (monthly). So it might lower your cost if you transfer your domain to such registrar. (Assuming you can/want to do that.)

If you provide your top-level domain (ie .com, .net, .eu, .de, ... etc), I may be able to suggest such a registrar.

**[Update]**

Came across this solution for .pl domain.

[Gandi](https://www.gandi.net/en/domain/email?c=PL) provide .pl domain and comes with "unlimited aliases and forwarding addresses". The .pl price is €20 per year. So it would come down to what you are paying for your domain now.

Comment: I've asked my registrar some time ago, but they don't provide such feature if I don't buy hosting there. I have .pl domain.

Comment: Sorry, I’m not aware of any for .pl

Comment: @Djent came across a registrar for .pl with mail redirect.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another alternative - [Zoho Mail](https://www.zoho.com/mail/).
It can do [catch all](https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/adminconsole/catch-all-setup.html) and [forwarding](https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/email-forwarding.html).

All the [pricing plans](https://www.zoho.com/mail/zohomail-pricing.html) are lower than your current subscription of 6,5EUR.
(Note: They also have a free plan, but it does not support forwarding.)

Comment: Zoho looks really great. They seem reliable and really cheap. I have trouble determining which plan I need to have. It seems like catch-all is available in free plan, and forwarding is paid feature?

Comment: Forwarding is not available in the free plan based on the help link above. I suggest you chat or contact them to clarify to verify.

Answer (score 0):

Here is yet another way. Use AWS SES to receive incoming email and to forward it. This [AWS blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/messaging-and-targeting/forward-incoming-email-to-an-external-destination/) describe how exactly it can be setup.

Depending on your email volume, it probably cost lower than what you are paying. Given that the services involved - SES, S3, Lambda and network traffic all have [free tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/). (The end of the above blog post also give some cost estimates)

This method will require some knowledge to setup or someone can help you do that.

Comment: That sounds like it can be easily broken by misconfiguration. I need a reliable service as I use the catch-all e-mails everywhere.